# Using URI Scheme to Launch Program in NotePad++

Tags: html, url-scheme

I'm writing an html document with links that, when the user clicks on them, should open a program with an argument.

As an example to test this process out I've attempted to created a URI scheme that should launch notepad++.exe with an argument of a simple text file I've written

Running straight from PowerShell looks like this, and successfully opens my text file

```
PS C:\> & 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' 'C:\TestingDocument.txt'
```

I followed the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
for creating a URI (I've called mine "NOTEPAD++"). And wrote an html file like the following to test this out:

```
<html> <body> <a href="NOTEPAD++:C:\\TestingDocument.txt" >Test</p> </body> </html>
```

However when I click on the "Test" link in the web browser, notepad++ gets launched, but does not also open my text file...

I'm guessing maybe my syntax for `NOTEPAD++:C:\\TestingDocument.txt` isn't right for passing in an argument?? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

added registry key `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NOTEPADPLUSPLUS` with:

- `(Default)` of `URL:NOTEPADPLUSPLUS Protocol`
- `URL Protocol` of empty string
- `DefaultIcon` with `(Default)` of `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`
- `shell` -> `open` -> `command` with `(Default)` of `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"`

Comment: Did you try naming your URI `NotepadPlusPlus` instead of `Notepad++`? The `+` could be the issue, since it's used to represent a space (just like `%20`).

Comment: Changed to `NOTEPADPLUSPLUS` and same result...

Comment: What about `NOTEPADPLUSPLUS:"C:\\TestingDocument.txt"`? Do you have the actual registry keys you wrote?

Comment: See edit with registry keys. Also adding the quotes as you showed didn't work.

Comment: Look, I'm not quite sure what's going on. I believe `(Default)` should actually be a `@`. This answer is the same as this one on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/585758/can-notepad-be-made-to-open-file-links-in-itself (they work with `.reg` files, so you could create one and import it by double clicking it). Another option would be to define the command as `"\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""` (note the extra quotes and extra backslashes).

Answer (score 1):

Your handle for Notepad++ doesn't work because the full URI is passed as an argument, not just the remaining part after the `NOTEPAD++:` url scheme. See the documentation about it from: [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the specified open command specified in the registry contains a %1 parameter, Internet Explorer **passes the URI** to the registered pluggable protocol handler application.

So, you are basically calling...

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "NOTEPAD++:C:\\TestingDocument.txt"
```

... and Notepad++ doesn't understand your parameter.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand. It was never really my intention to use Notepad++ I was just using it to start understanding using URI Schemes. This is actually going to be used with a custom application I'm writing. I guess in my programs argument handler I'll have to deal with parsing out all arguments from the first argument. Not as elegant of a solution as I was expecting, but I can still work with that...